# bitfinex api v2 error, invalid key

Tags: python, api, request, urllib, bitcoin

I am trying to make a basic authenticated api call to their new v2 api and getting an invalid api key error returned.

I reissued the api key just to verify, same error.

```
from time import time
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import hmac

APIkey = b'myapikeyyouarenotsupposedtosee'
secret = b'myceeeeecretkeyyyy'

url = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/auth/r/wallets'

payload = {
    #'request':'/auth/r/wallets',
    'nonce': int(time() * 1000),
}

paybytes = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf8')
print(paybytes)

sign = hmac.new(secret, paybytes, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print(sign)

headers = {
    'Key': APIkey,
    'Sign': sign
}

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers, data=paybytes)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
    print(the_page)
```

How do I make an authenticated api call to the new v2 API for bitfinex?

Comment: In case you need it for PHP or want to compare with PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851626/2635490

Comment: I have just found out, that the `bfx-signature` string must be lower case.

Answer (score 11):

Your headers are wrong. I was also trying to do this and tried using the [example code](https://bitfinex.readme.io/v2/docs/rest-auth) from the bitfinex v2 api docs, however their example contained a bug in that they needed to encode the strings into UTF-8 byte arrays first. So I've fixed it and posting the entire example below.

```
#
# Example Bitfinex API v2 Auth Python Code
#
import requests  # pip install requests
import json
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import os
import time #for nonce

class BitfinexClient(object):
    BASE_URL = "https://api.bitfinex.com/"
    KEY = "API_KEY_HERE"
    SECRET = "API_SECRET_HERE"

    def _nonce(self):
        # Returns a nonce
        # Used in authentication
        return str(int(round(time.time() * 10000)))

    def _headers(self, path, nonce, body):
        secbytes = self.SECRET.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
        signature = "/api/" + path + nonce + body
        sigbytes = signature.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
        h = hmac.new(secbytes, sigbytes, hashlib.sha384)
        hexstring = h.hexdigest()
        return {
            "bfx-nonce": nonce,
            "bfx-apikey": self.KEY,
            "bfx-signature": hexstring,
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }

    def req(self, path, params = {}):
        nonce = self._nonce()
        body = params
        rawBody = json.dumps(body)
        headers = self._headers(path, nonce, rawBody)
        url = self.BASE_URL + path
        resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=rawBody, verify=True)
        return resp

    def active_orders(self):
        # Fetch active orders
        response = self.req("v2/auth/r/orders")
        if response.status_code == 200:
          return response.json()
        else:
          print('error, status_code = ', response.status_code)
          return ''

# fetch all your orders and print out
client = BitfinexClient()
result = client.active_orders()
print(result)
```

Comment: Can you add some example inputs and resulting output to make check against?

Answer (score -2):

Why not use one of the open source api clients out there ? and you can compare to your work . 
https://github.com/scottjbarr/bitfinex
https://github.com/tuberculo/bitfinex

Comment: Those are using the v1 API.
I am trying to write to the most current version.

Comment: I actually have a V1 connection as is.