# Bitfinex API v2 Authenticated Endpoints using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am sure I am so close, but just off. I am trying to return my wallet balances with the Bitfinex v2 API, but I keep getting the "invalid key" error.

After having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830995/bitfinex-api-v2-error-invalid-key) I think my issue might be related, but updating my code with `utf8_encode` didn't fix the issue.

This is my first time using cURL, so I'm not very confident that I have set all of the options correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help that's offered.

My code so far (you'll have to trust that `_APISECRET` and `_APIKEY` are set):

```
CONST _APIPATH = "v2/auth/r/wallets";
CONST _APIURL = "https://api.bitfinex.com/";

$nonce = strval(time()*1000);
$body = json_encode(array());
$signature = '/api/' . _APIPATH . $nonce . $body;

$signature = hash_hmac('sha384', $signature, utf8_encode(_APISECRET));

$headers = array('bfx-nonce' => $nonce, 'bfx-apikey' => utf8_encode(_APIKEY), 'bfx-signature' => $signature, 'content-type' => 'application/json');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _APIURL . _APIPATH);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: this isn't javascript, PHP strings are binary safe, where do you get this api key, if its incorrectly encoded?

Comment: The API key is tied to my account (you get it from within the account interface). I am confident I have entered it correctly.

Comment: I have just found out that the `bfx-signature` string must be lower case.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today. Here my working solution:

```
/**
 * Bitfinex API V2 REST AUTHENTICATED ENDPOINT
 *
 * @param $method
 * @param array $request
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
private function queryPrivate($method, array $request = array())
{
    // build the POST data string
    $postData = (count($request)) ? '/' . implode("/", $request) : '';

    $nonce      = (string) number_format(round(microtime(true) * 100000), 0, ".", "");
    $path       = "/api/v2".'/auth/r/'.$method.$postData.$nonce;
    $signature  = hash_hmac("sha384", utf8_encode($path), utf8_encode($this->secret));

    $headers = array(
        "content-type: application/json",
        "content-length: ",
        "bfx-apikey: " . $this->key,
        "bfx-signature: " . $signature,
        "bfx-nonce: " . $nonce
    );

    $url = $this->url.'/auth/r/' . $method . $postData;

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    if (!$result=curl_exec($this->curl)) {
        return $this->curl_error($this->curl);
    } else {
        // var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function with

```
    $param = array();
    $this->queryPrivate("wallets", $param);

    $param = array('tIOTETH','hist');
    $this->queryPrivate("trades", $param);
```

Good luck!

Comment: does this work when there is postdata? this line seems off $url = $this->url.'/auth/r/' . $method . $postData;