# Bitfinex API V2 BUG apikey: invalid code 10100

Tags: php, error-handling

I have searched everywhere and unfortunately, to this day, No one ever found a proper solution to this. Therefore I want to ask this question to confirm if this is a `BUG` in the API Authentication system of `Bitfinex`. I wrote the codes in PHP. Should you find any problem in my code, you can mention it and I will test it to see if it works. I should mention that I have tested many situations and still get the error of `apikey: invalid` & `code 10100`. e.g. encoding the `secret` and the `payload` to UTF-8.

Note: This approach is also fully tested and did not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851626/7644018

```
private function nonce(){
    return time()*1000; //Also time()*1000*1000 is tested
}

private function signature($api_path,$body,$nonce){
    $str =  "/api/$api_path" . $nonce . json_encode($body);
    return hash_hmac('sha384',$str,$this->secret); //Also UTF-8 encoding $str & secret are tested
}

public function getTradeFee(string $currency) : array{
    $api_path = "v2/auth/r/summary";
    $request_path = $this->auth_base_url . $api_path;
    $body = []; //params are not needed for this path
    $nonce = $this->nonce();
    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json" ,
        "bfx-nonce: $nonce" ,
        "bfx-apikey: " . $this->key , //Key is double checked and is correct (With full permissions)
        "bfx-signature: " . $this->signature($api_path,$body,$nonce)
    ];
    $curl = curl_init($request_path);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $info = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $info = json_decode($info);
    return $info;
}
```

Comment: See if the [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851626/7644018) might help? ... in their example, they have `utf8_encode` on two of the signature parameters, if that could be part of the issue?

Comment: @PaulT. Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately that approach also does not work. Even multiplying the time with 100,000 does not affect it at all.

Comment: Ok, well search this site for the terms `bitfinex v2 invalid code 10100` there are other answers. Some are in languages other than PHP too, but it's about finding the piece's to make it work

Comment: @PaulT. Thank you. I've searched however, there are little questions related to the matter. Sure the languages are not a problem as I'm familiar with many. I will keep looking to some extent before giving up for sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and testing different approaches for hours I can finally confirm that this is a BUG due to the lack of support for the `Bitfinex V2 REST API` I suppose. You can refer to this link https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/docs/introduction in order to use V1 API. It is apparently more stable and working. I hope this helps. This answer is valid for this date and the API may one day improve.